# MySQL: TABLE_ROWS column of information_schema and count(*) are different

Tags: mysql

I think `TABLE_ROWS` column from `information_schema.partitions` table and result of `COUNT(*)` have to be same, but in my table, these values are different. Is it possible to be different?

```
mysql> select partition_name, partition_ordinal_position, table_rows from information_schema.partitions where table_name='lootinfo';
+----------------+----------------------------+------------+
| PARTITION_NAME | PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION | TABLE_ROWS |
+----------------+----------------------------+------------+
| future         |                          3 |          0 |
| p_202206       |                          1 |      10676 |
| p_202207       |                          2 |          0 |
+----------------+----------------------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from lootinfo partition (p_202206);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    10360 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I didn't insert or delete any of rows between two queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TABLES_ROWS` is an estimate, and `COUNT` is the exact number.

According to the docs :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-infoschema-excerpt/8.0/en/information-schema-partitions-table.html

> For partitioned InnoDB tables, the row count given in the TABLE_ROWS column is only an estimated value used in SQL optimization, and may not always be exact.